# How do I stop the play/pause keyboard buttons from launching iTunes on Mountain Lion?

Tags: itunes, keyboard, macos

The play/pause keyboard buttons always launch iTunes. I want to use a Subsonic client, Thumper. The buttons control Thumper correctly, but I want to prevent iTunes launching.

There was a [hacky solution](http://lifehacker.com/5651055/free-your-macs-media-keys-from-itunes-no-manual-hacking-required) available previously, but that no longer works.

Is there a way to disable this iTunes behaviour?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I searched everywhere for a clean solution. Many solutions that worked for Lion and below no longer worked for Mountain Lion. However, this works and it took me hours to find. Enjoy!

http://gavinroy.com/posts/disabling-default-itunes-launch-behavior-with.html

From the website:

> In a search for a non-hacky way to disable direct mappings to iTunes for the play/pause/next/previous buttons in the keyboard in OSX, I stumbled across the "Remote control daemon" (rcd). As it turns out, disabling the iTunes launch behavior for these keys is as easy as unloading rcd with the following command:

```
launchctl unload -w /System/Library/LaunchAgents/com.apple.rcd.plist
```

Comment: Doing the unloading tip above disabled my headphone volume up/down buttons. Be wary!

Comment: `/System/Library/LaunchAgents/com.apple.rcd.plist: Operation not permitted while System Integrity Protection is engaged` — i.e. no longer works in High Sierra.

Comment: @DisplayName this tutorials explains how to disable SIP as well as an option to prevent iTunes from opening: https://jeangalea.com/mac-keyboard-itunes-disable/

Answer (score 0):

If you press <kbd>⌘ command</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>pause</kbd> it doesn't open iTunes.
Also it sometimes works if you only press <kbd>⌘ command</kbd> + <kbd>pause</kbd> or <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>pause</kbd>

Comment: This doesn't sound like an answer to me, is it an answer? If so, please be more certain and edit your answer.